# Extreme Lag After Loading Palette from Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am currently making a wallpaper app in Flutter. I am using the [palette_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator) package to extract colors from the image. The problem is while the app is extracting colors from the image. The UI freezes for a solid 3 seconds, after which the colors are shown on the screen. After the colors have been rendered, the whole screen suffers from jank and lag. All animations on that screen perform very badly. Popping off that screen removes the jank and lag. Here is the code I am using:

```dart
 Future<PaletteGenerator?> updatePalette() async {
 var cache = DefaultCacheManager();
 File file = await cache.getSingleFile(widget.wall.url);
    ui.Image image = await load(file);
    palette = await PaletteGenerator.fromImage(
      image,
      maximumColorCount: 7,
    );
 return palette;
  }

 Future<ui.Image> load(File file) async {
 var data = await file.readAsBytes();
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data);
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
 return fi.image;
  }

FutureBuilder<PaletteGenerator?>(
                    future: updatePalette(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData)
                        return MyBottomSheet(
                            wall: widget.wall, palette: snapshot.data);

                      return LinearProgressIndicator();
                    }),
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) package to implement Isolates. The function you are using is a heavy function. Using an Isolated function avoids putting too much pressure on the main thread.

Example code:

```dart
void updatePalette() async {
    var cache = DefaultCacheManager();
    File file = await cache.getSingleFile(url);
    var port = ReceivePort();
    var isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(
      computePalette,
      [file.readAsBytesSync(), port.sendPort],
    );
    port.listen((msg) {
      List<int> data = msg;
      data.forEach((d) => colorList.add(Color(d)));
      isolate.kill();
      port.close();
    });
  }

void computePalette(List<Object> args) async {
  var image = args[0] as Uint8List;
  var port = args[1] as SendPort;
  var img = Image.memory(image);
  var palette = await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
    img.image,
    maximumColorCount: 7,
  );
  List<int> colors = [];
  palette.colors.forEach((element) => colors.add(element.value));
  port.send(colors);
}
```

Comment: Just a note all the messing about with making colors an int list and passing the image as bytes is because flutter isolates only support primitive types